# Loading Driver in QEMU Running Windows on Windows

Tags: windows, windows-10, virtual-machine, qemu

I want to run Windows 10 on Windows 10 with QEMU (not with other software). I downloaded QEMU, and set up environment variable. I also got the Windows 10 iso file, renamed it to win10.iso, and put that in the same directory as the QEMU folder. Then I ran this command in the QEMU folder with cmd prompt: `qemu-system-x86_64.exe -boot d -cdrom win10.iso -m 2048` 
It worked fine, but when it asked for the drive, I got confused. [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wvT6y.png).
I clicked on the first option, and it said [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q7jKo.png). So clicked on the second option, and it gave me [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3RyqU.png). I clicked "load driver" and it gave me [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/veRi6.png). How do I make a device driver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You misunderstood windows installer. The window on the first image asks you for installation type - installing a new version or upgrading an existing. The upgrade option is only available when you have an installed version and runs the installer from a booted windows, not when booting from installation media. So installing a new version is your choice. The window on third image says windows installer cant find any disks where it can install the OS. This is because you ran qemu with a cdrom and no disks. The solution here is not to load a driver, but run qemu with a hard disk.
First create a disk, for example so:

```
qemu-img.exe create -f qcow2 win10.qcow2 50G
```

Then run qemu with this disk:

```
qemu-system-x86_64.exe -boot d -cdrom win10.iso -m 2048 win10.qcow2
```